# How do you set and get cookie values in Micronaut monolith?

Tags: cookies, thymeleaf, micronaut

The question is simple. How do you set and get cookie values in Micronaut monolith that uses Thymeleaf for server side rendering?

I already know how to get the cookie values based on the solution here

**Bind the cookie value(s): https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#binding
And then pass them as the model to your thymeleaf view:
https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-views/latest/guide/index.html**

but what about setting a cookie value programmatically since I'm using a third party auth provider?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that thymeleaf makes any difference.
But following `Groovy` sample shows how to receive and set cookies in a micronaut controller.

```
@Controller
class CookieController {

    @Get
    HttpResponse<ModelAndView> cookie(HttpRequest<?> request) {

        // receive cookie
        def myCookie = request.cookies.all.find { it.name == "my-cookie" }
        println myCookie?.value

        return HttpResponse.ok(new ModelAndView("view", [key: "value"]))
                // set cookie
                .cookie(new SimpleCookie("another-cookie", "value"))
    }
}
```

Comment: After so long, I've been playing around with cookies and Micronaut, and I've bump into a problem where I can't even clear and remove cookies. What is the proper way of doing it these days?